# Load Child Bundle depending on URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have created a bundle that provide default functionality for some use case.
No I want to direct X URLs to this project. No problem up to this point, all URLs point to the `/web` folder.

But now I want to create child bundles to modify some functionality / behavior / appearance for each URL. What is the best way to load different child bundles for different URLs?

My approach would be to detect URL in `AppKernel` and load at this point the specific child bundle. Does it make sense or is there a better way?

Comment: Please provide some code with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed placing your code in the AppKernel seems a good way to handle that but you'll have a cache issue.

Example :

If your Request A loads bundle A, it will be cached.
If your Request B loads bundle B but not bundle A, you'll get an error related to the loading of bundle A's classes.

Another issue will be your routing, you'll have to create separate routing files for your different bundle sets.

My approach would be environment dependent, in your front controller, you'll catch the host and then use a different environment (hosta_dev / hosta_prod / hostb_dev / hostb_prod) for each URL. This will create separate cache and allow you to have separate config / routing files.

You'll still have to make modifications in your AppKernel anyway (for example you'll have to load the "dev" bundles not only if the environment is "dev" or "test" but also if the environment contains "dev" or "test").

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds very god, i will test it and give feedback! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create three services:

1. main
2. `A` which inherited from main
3. `B` which inherited from main

Then define in your configuration `my_service` to `main` by default.
On Service initialization for controller with url A reconfigure it to `A`. same for `B`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will first try the approach of @Michaël Garrez because i think it fits better to my needs.